# I have to read from an excel file (in xlsx format) and then manipulate that data

Tags: java

I am doing a project for class and need help with this part. I just need to know if there is a way to read from an excel file line by line and manipulate that data. Specifically I am creating a "customer" object, and each line in the excel file is the data for the customer(name, address, etc.). I can't use any third party libraries or anything like that.

Is there a way to do this using BufferReader or FileInputStream. Those are the only 2 ways to read files we have gone over in class. I also tried saving it as a CVS file but it doesn't let me do so.
Or Scanner using a delimiter?

Would I be able to just copy everything into a notepad and manipulate it from there?

Comment: That's nice. Good luck with your homework.

Comment: Why can't you use a third party library?

Comment: Extract POI into your project and say you are done

Comment: Just what my professor said. I figure he must have a way to do this without using one or we would be allowed to. Is there a way to put it in notepad and do it that way. I have to save each column in a varible of some sort.

Comment: then see how POI is implemented - everything is there

Answer (score 2):

Well, not using any third party library will be very hard as a homework.
I highly recommand to use [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/)

[Here](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-write-to-an-excel-file-using-poi.html) is a good tutorial to start with POI.

Comment: I can't use anything like that. I wish I could. Do you happen to know of any other way to do this. I just need some examples.

Comment: If it was a CSV file, then I could have told you to write directly in a CSV file you create using known java objects. But Excel.. That would be very difficult for you to reimplement something Apache have spent quite long time to develop it.

Comment: Thats what I figured. I thought if I saved it as a CVS file I might be able to work with it but it didn't like that very much. Unless I did it wrong.

Comment: I also believe he ment CSV file - try this tool for easy parsing: http://jodd.org/api/jodd/util/CsvUtil.html